# Tableau Regex Extract date from file name

Tags: regex, date, expression, extract, tableau-prep

I have a field that has the text file name being used as the data source. The file name is formatted like "file_name_example_2022-11-17_14.45.56.txt" with the "2022-11-17_14.45.56" being the date and time. I know I can do a series of RIGHT and LEFTs to extract the date time as a separate field, but I wanted to see if REGEX_EXTRACT would provide a cleaner way to do it. I've been looking at regular expression documentation and can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to end up with a full date time field.

So far I have tried

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([File Paths], '\d(.+)')
```

and that results in "022-11-17_14.45.56.txt"

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([File Paths], '\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/volQMb/1).

*Details*:

- `\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}` - four digits, `-`, one or two digits, `-`, one or two digits
- `_` - a `_` char
- `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}` - one or two digits, `.`, one or two digits, `.`, one or two digits.